# Continuous swinging machine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

I'm making art piece that is hanging from roof and I would like to have it in continuous swinging motion. What kind of mechanism could be used in this case?

info about the art piece

- about 16kg
- shape is rectangular
- hanging about 2.7 meters from the roof

..

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to design around the natural period of oscillation as this will minimise the amount of energy required.

$$ T = 2 \pi \sqrt {\frac L g} $$

where $T$ is the periodic time, $L$ is the length and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. For your case this works out as

$$ T = 2 \pi \sqrt {\frac {2.7}{9.81}} = 3.3\ \text s $$

The actual result may be affected by air resistance. (Your artwork sounds large.)

You have several options for the actuator. It could be a solenoid or rotating wheel with a pin on its face to push the string on each revolution. I would expect that you could do this about 100 mm below the suspension point but this should be easy to determine using a stopwatch (or a metronome app on your phone<sup>1</sup>) and a little impulse from your finger.

That exercise should give you some idea whether or not it's going to work and the amount of energy and distance you need to put in on every cycle.

<sup>1</sup> Set the metronome to 72.7 beats per minute 4/4 time and impulse on the 1 every time.